# Can std::numeric_limits::digits be negative?

Tags: c++

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits

Can the value ever be negative?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could add your own specialisation for one of your own types and put in a negative `digits` member. For primitive types? No. The relevant place in the standard (as of 2011) is 18.3.2.4 (8-10):

> ```
> static constexpr int digits;
> ```
>
> 8 Number of `radix` digits that can be represented without change.
>
> 9 For integer types, the number of non-sign bits in the representation
>
> 10 For floating point types, the number of `radix` digits in the mantissa.

None of those can possibly be negative.

If your actual question is: "why, when `digits` cannot be negative, is it a signed `int`?", then your guess is as good as mine. My guess is that it is because arithmetic with signed types is less surprising. For example, `std::numeric_limits<int>::digits - std::numeric_limits<long>::digits` is not larger than zero this way.

Comment: Would such a specialization allowed?

Comment: Scott Meyers seems to think so, at least (Effective C++, 3rd edition, Item 25). According to him, it's okay to totally specialize templates in `std`, but not to add anything new (such as function template overloads). He doesn't mention chapter and verse, unfortunately. The context in which he mentions it is specializing `std::swap` for user-supplied types. EDIT: Chapter and verse is 17.4.3.1 in C++03.

Comment: Yes, specializing certain templates is legal. They must still fulfill the contract advertized for the base-version though, which imho `digits < 0` would not.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a specialization of `std::numeric_limits` for your own type (§[namespace.std]/1):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified. **A program may add a template specialization for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type** and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly prohibited.

There doesn't seem to be any language to prohibit negative numbers for things like number of digits in §[limits.numeric], which is where you'd expect it if it existed. On the other hand, a negative number of digits doesn't make any sense either, and would pretty clearly run contrary to the description of the field, even though there's no *direct* prescription that the number be non-negative.

It is entirely possible and reasonable for `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` to produce the value 0 though. In fact, it's basically required to happen for most non-arithmetic types (§[numeric.limits]/1):

```
The default numeric_limits<T> template shall have all members, but with 0 or false 
values.
```

A few things that might initially *seem* like arithmetic types actually are *not*. For one obvious example, `std::complex<T>` is *not* an arithmetic type.

Bottom line: I'd expect the number of digits to be strictly positive for all built-in types. Although there's nothing to *directly* prohibit a negative value for user-defined types, it seems like such a value would have to be an error--if the value is arithmetic, the number of digits should be strictly positive, and if it's not arithmetic, a specialization of `std::numeric_limits` should not be provided for that type (in which case the default with a value of 0 would be used).